# SQL Server query perfomance tuning with group by and join clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have been experiencing performance concerns over job and  I could fortunately find the query causing the slowness..

```
select   name from Student a, Student_Temp b
where a.id = b.id and
a.name in (select name from Student
group by name having count(*) = @sno)
group by a.name having count(*) = @sno
OPTION (MERGE JOIN, LOOP JOIN)
```

This particular query is iteratively called many times slowing down the performance..

`Student` table has 8 Million records and `Student_temp` receives 5-20 records in the iteration process each time.
`Student` table has composite primary key on ( `id` and `name`)
and `sno` = No of records in `Student_Temp`.

My questions are below,
1) why does this query show performance issues.
2) could you guys give a more efficient way of writing this piece ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Not sure you even need "and
a.name in (select name from Student
group by name having count(*) = @sno)" part

Comment: I think you could use inner join :select name from Student a INNER JOIN  Student_Temp b ON a.id = b.id...

Comment: subquery do not make any sense .

Comment: @PeterRing It IS an inner join.

Comment: How is the performance if you remove the query hint?

Comment: @twinkles : Its the same even after removing the hint.. The code is 15 years old and its time to rewrite..

Comment: What is the purpose of checking if count(*) grouped by name equals @sno? If you want to check if all the records have the same name, use: select count(distinct a.name)
from Student a
inner join Student_Temp b on a.id = b.id

Answer (score 1):

It's repeating the same logic unnecessarily. You really just want:

- Of the Student(s) who also exist in Student_temp
- what names exist @sno times?

Try this:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    Student a JOIN
    Student_Temp b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY
    name
HAVING
    count(*) = @sno
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns the following result: Give me all names that are `@sno` times in the table `Student` and exactly once in `Student_temp`.

You can rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM Student a
INNER JOIN Student_temp b
ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = @sno
```

You should omit the query hint unless you are absolutely sure that the query optimizer screws up.

**EDIT:** There is of course a difference between the queries: if for instance `@sno=2` then a name that shows up once in `Student` but twice in `Student_temp` would be included in my query but not in the original. I depends on what you really want to achieve whether that needs to be adressed or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Twinles. I have a question. in your answer you have given as " all the names " .. this is not true. the value a.name is assigned to a variable. like select @nm=a.name .... Are you sure that your query will give exactly same result as of mine

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but yes: your query can return more than one row as well.

Comment: Please consider getting somebody with database experience on your team, there could be even more problems with your system that are slowing you down (for instance the part where the query is "iteratively called many times").

Comment: Or the fact that you have a composite key over `id` and `name`.

Comment: Twinkles . you are right !! even the tuned query provided by you is slow.. I guess its due to indexes. thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go**

```
select   name 
from Student a
inner join Student_Temp b
on a.id = b.id
group by a.name 
HAVING COUNT(*) = @sno
```